# How can i do this query in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Query details

```
SELECT userfbimages_id, count( * ) FROM votes GROUP BY userfbimages_id 
HAVING count( * ) >= ALL (SELECT count( * ) FROM votes GROUP BY userfbimages_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::statement('SELECT userfbimages_id, count() FROM votes 
               GROUP BY userfbimages_id 
               HAVING count() >= ALL (SELECT count(*) FROM votes GROUP BY userfbimages_id)');
```

Comment: i want to : SELECT * FROM votes GROUP BY userfbimages_id 
HAVING count(*) >= ALL (SELECT count(*) FROM votes GROUP BY userfbimages_id)

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::statement()

Comment: Sorry !! i actually added this query in my controller and it returns Null !! $this->model->where('SELECT * FROM votes 
               GROUP BY userfbimages_id 
               HAVING count() >= ALL (SELECT count(*) FROM votes GROUP BY userfbimages_id)') !!!and i tested the Query in my SQL it worked :(

Comment: Sorry but It's hard to tell without seeing the other parts of code.

Comment: i just want to return all the max count grouped by userfbimages_id !! my query returns 3columns when i run it in my sql db not null !!! i have vote table in which the user_id , userfbimages_id (the id of voted images) here i want to select all the max voted images !!